# Ternary operators does not work as needed in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator, eslint

I fall into the non-understanding with ternary operators. So, I work with **ESLint plugin** in my **VS Code** and this plugin politely tells me in the console, that the first type of code below is not very good writen by giving me the warning error: `Unexpected mix of '&&' and '||'`.

So, this is my code for example:

```
: tempFilter === 'all' ? iteam.text.match(value) && iteam.status === 'active' || iteam.status === 'done'
```

**ESLint** propouse me to rewrite it by wrapping the tied condition around `||` in the brackets `()`:

```
: tempFilter === 'all' ? iteam.text.match(value) && (iteam.status === 'active' || iteam.status === 'done')
```

But after that my condition does not work as expects in the array filter function. My question is - what is I missed? Why after **ESLint** improvements the code is broke, or we do not need to implement any bracers in this case?

The code of filtering to understand where is I use the part of code above:

```
    let filteredButtonsDown = state.iteams.buttons.filter(button => {
        return tempFilter === 'done' && value === '' ? button.status === 'done' 
            : tempFilter === 'active' && value === '' ? button.status === 'active'
            : tempFilter === 'all' && value === '' ? button.status === 'active' || button.status === 'done'
            : tempFilter === 'done' ? button.text.match(value) && button.status === 'done'
            : tempFilter === 'active' ? button.text.match(value) && button.status === 'active'
            : tempFilter === 'all' ? button.text.match(value) && button.status === 'active' || button.status === 'done'
            : button
    });
```

Comment: The logic is that we must filter an array and give on output the array that consists of `buttons` with `status  = 'active' or status = 'done' or bouth. And it works without the `()` bracets, although it id propouses by **ESLint**. That is the main question

Comment: (1) chill with the down votes, please ... if the answer isn't correct, help by explaining your question better. (2) if you're having a problem with ternary, don't use it, just go with a traditional if/else structure and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the logic in this line:

```
    : tempFilter === 'all' && value === '' ? button.status === 'active' || button.status === 'done'
```

In translation you are saying:

if tempFilter is equal to "all" and value is equal to "", then button.status is equal to "active" or button.status is equal to "done". That doesn't make sense as you are ambiguous about what the value of button.status is and are not explicitly setting its value.

Ask yourself in the above quoted code: What is the value of button.status if the opening condition evaluates to true. That is the issue here. You are assigning the value as 'active' or 'done' which doesn't make sense. You must only assign one value. Either 'active' or 'done' not both, that is what the ESLint is complaining about.

Comment: The logic is that we must filter an array and give on output the array that consists of buttons with `status = 'active' or status = 'done'` or **bouth**. And it works without the `()` bracets, although it is propouses by **ESLint**. That is the main question